# Find callers Android phone info

Tags: android, telephony, gsm, 3g, imei

I am using 3g GSM network.

I need to know if it is possible to find the IMEI number, location info etc. of the calling android phone from my android phone, programatically.

Thre are two scenarios: While I am making the call, I need the IMEI of the callee. Also when I receive the call I need the IMEI of the caller.

Here All parties are running android in their phones.

Also please note that these android phones cannot use internet connection to transmit data [in which case this question stands irrelevant]

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for making this possible is to involve the mobile network or the remote device. Information like the remote subscribers IMEI or location may only be retrieved from the remote device or the network.

Since you rule out internet connections, out-of-band queries for this information seems to be rather not feasible.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to know if it is possible to find the IMEI number, location info etc. of the calling android phone from my android phone, programatically.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons (beyond probably being technically impossible).

Answer (score -1):

```
private String getIMEI(){
     TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     return manager.getDeviceId();
 }
```

Comment: This will find the local phone's IMEI number not the IMEI for the calling phone.